# Have trouble with processing image in web page

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing

I have been trying to upload an image and convert it into grayscale version then display both images on a webpage. I have test and verified the working of the javascript code locally and it works. However when I integrate it into my webpage only the orignal image is being uploaded. The greyscale image is not being generated or the function is not being processed.

```
    function doUpload(){
  var image = new SimpleImage(inputFile);
  image.drawTo(CanvasOG);
  var imageGS = grayScale(image);
  imageGS.drawTo(CanvasGS);
  //var NewImage = grayScale(image);
  //NewImage.drawTo(CanvasGS)
}
```

Can you tell me what went wrong?

PS Im using the Duke university's learn to program course's SimpleImage library for the functions to read the images and pixel values

Im posting a link to the codepen page incase you want to see the entire code with the html page
https://codepen.io/girish-kumar-peddi/pen/PoPBxKb

Answer (score 0):

The nature of SimpleImage.js `drawTo()` contains a `setTimeout()`. Thus the `imageData` is not set instantly, but after 100ms. So after the image is drawn to the canvas, wait sometime before manipulating the image data. Enclosed the `drawTo()` implementation below.

```
 // Draws to the given canvas, setting its size to match SimpleImage's size
    drawTo: function (toCanvas) {
        if (this.imageData != null) {
            __SimpleImageUtilities.flush(this.context, this.imageData);
            toCanvas.width = this.getWidth();
            toCanvas.height = this.getHeight();
            toCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this.canvas, 0, 0, toCanvas.width, toCanvas.height);
        }
        else {
            var myself = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                myself.drawTo(toCanvas);
            }, 100);
        }
    },
```